# Custom tooltip is creating double tooltips visible in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, tooltip

~ I am using a very slightly modified version of the jQuery tooltip script at: http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/01/ -- the only modification i made is to set it to initiate the tooltip on area links in addition to regular a links. In the sample at the link above there is no problem in IE browsers - the built-in IE tooltip is not showing, only the custom one. But on my page the built-in tooltip in IE is still showing in addition to the custom tooltip. Any idea what could be causing this?

Here is the script as I am using it:

```
this.tooltipText = function () {
    /* CONFIG */
    xOffset = 0;
    yOffset = 0;
    /* END CONFIG */
    $("a.tooltipText, area.tooltipText").hover(function (e) {
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";
        $("body").append("<p id='tooltipText'>" + this.t + "</p>");
        $("#tooltipText").css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px").fadeIn("fast");
    }, function () {
        this.title = this.t;
        $("#tooltipText").remove();
    });
    $("a.tooltipText, area.tooltipText").mousemove(function (e) {
        $("#tooltipText").css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });
};
// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function () {
    tooltipText();
});
```

And here is a sample from the html to trigger the tooltip:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="9,359,617,391" href="/link-here/" onclick="window.open(this.href,'','toolbar=no, location=no, addressbar=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=510, height=580, top=50, left=150'); return false;" target="_blank" class="tooltipText" title="<strong>First part bold</strong>  Rest of tooltip text goes here <strong>Read More...</strong>" />
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing differently from the script used here: http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/01/

As always, any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, have you checked the console (F12) to see if any errors are happening?

Comment: nesting html tags into attributes of another tag is invalid html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nesting of tags within attributes of another tag is invalid html and is likely source of IE problem

In order to keep the full text of the title within the title attribute, and still be able to separate it into bold and normal you could use a delimiter like "|" and split the title at the delimiter when the tooltip is constructed in script.

```
<img title="This will be bold | this is normal" src=""/>
```

modified code

```
this.tooltipText = function () {
/* CONFIG */
xOffset = 0;
yOffset = 0;
/* END CONFIG */
$("a.tooltipText, area.tooltipText").hover(function (e) {
    this.t = this.title;
    this.title = "";

    /* split title at pipe delimiter*/
    this.title_parts= this.t.split('|');
    this.tip_content='<strong>'+this.title_parts[0]+'</strong>'+this.title_parts[1]; 

    $("body").append("<p id='tooltipText'><strong>" +/*change===> */ this.tip_content + "</p>");
    $("#tooltipText").css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px").fadeIn("fast");
}, function () {
    this.title = this.t;
    $("#tooltipText").remove();
});
$("a.tooltipText, area.tooltipText").mousemove(function (e) {
    $("#tooltipText").css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
});
```

};

EDIT: Following will remove titles completely on page load, and store in element data

```
this.tooltipText = function () {
    /* CONFIG */
    xOffset = 0;
    yOffset = 0;
    /* END CONFIG */
    $("a.tooltipText, area.tooltipText").hover(function (e) {
        this.t = $(this).data('title');

        /* split title at pipe delimiter*/
        this.title_parts= this.t.split('|');
        this.tip_content='<strong>'+this.title_parts[0]+'</strong>'+this.title_parts[1]; 

        $("body").append("<p id='tooltipText'><strong>" +/*change===> */ this.tip_content + "</p>");
        $("#tooltipText").css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px").fadeIn("fast");
    }, function () {
        /*this.title = this.t;*/
        $("#tooltipText").remove();
    }).attr('title', function(index, title){
        $(this).data('title', title);
        return '';
    });
    $("a.tooltipText, area.tooltipText").mousemove(function (e) {
        $("#tooltipText").css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Very useful! However i removed the tags from the title attr to test and it did not affect/fix the problem I'm asking about--

Comment: make sure page validates through w3C validator, can you provide a link?

Comment: yes the link is [link]http://www.aspyrallc.squarespace.com/imaging-solutions[/link] -- however i already tested removing the tags and it did not fix the problem. please limit feedback to helping with my question and not other issues unless they are related  :)

Comment: (rollover areas on the graphic to see the tooltips)

Comment: try new version I added. Should have empty titles once page loads, is not bullet proof if no title exists in original markup

Comment: This works great! Thanks for the tip and the fix!! I have spent hours on trying to figure this out! I'm still curious why the original script didnt work for me when it does in the sample link ... but just curiosity ....

Comment: likely something to do with area tag

Answer (score 0):

Solution for double tool tips problem in IE

Problem is solved. IE has this issue for IE 6,7,8,9 where it will show tool tip two times. IE needs to be told not to display the title. I found a code snipet on tne net

`<!--[if IE]><script>for(i =0;i<document.images.length;i++){document.images[i].alt='';}</script><![endif]-->`

this does not work but I changed the "alt" to title and bingo it works correctly

`<!--[if IE]><script>for(i =0;i<document.images.length;i++){document.images[i].title='';}</script><![endif]-->'`

place the snipet at the bottom or top of your page and your tooltip will render correctly in IE